# How to use + operator of a base class then return derived class?

Tags: c++

I have two classes. The base class, called `String` stores a `const char*` and the lenght of it, `len`. The derived class, called UString should has to manage an `upperCase` `static boolean` variable. If this is `true` the `string` in `ostream` has to be full uppercase. (this is a university task)

Where I have the problem (test file):

```
UString a("Hello ");
UString b("string");
UString c;
c = a + b;
```

The result should be: `Hello String`, but I get only `Hello`.

The important functions and operators in the base class for this task (these are provided by the teacher):

```
String& String::operator=(const String& rhs_s) {
    if (this != &rhs_s) {
        delete[] pData;
        len = rhs_s.len;
        pData = new char[len+1];
        strcpy(pData, rhs_s.pData);
    }
    return *this;
}

String String::operator+(const String& rhs_s) const {
    String temp;
    temp.len = len + rhs_s.len;
    delete []temp.pData;
    temp.pData = new char[temp.len+1];
    strcpy(temp.pData, pData);
    strcat(temp.pData, rhs_s.pData);
    return temp;
}

String operator+(char rhs_c) const { return *this + String(rhs_c);}
```

And how I tried to use them in UString class (here might be the problem somewhere):

```
UString& UString::operator=(const UString &s)
{
    String::operator=(s);
    return *this;
}


UString& UString::operator=(char s)
{
    String x(s);
    String::operator=(x);
    return *this;
}

UString& UString::operator=(String const &s)
{
    String::operator=(s);
    return *this;
}


UString UString::operator+(const UString& rhs_s) const {
    String::operator+(rhs_s);
    return this;
}

UString& UString::operator+(char s)
{
    String::operator+(UString(s));
    return *this;
}

UString UString::operator+(const String &s) const{
    String::operator+(s);
    return this;
}
```

All of the other functions and consturctors are working fine (according to the test).

Actually none of the plus operators are good :(

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: You should maybe not use strcpy or strcat... if you know the length, copy it yourself.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide [mcve]

Comment: Can't you just leave out the + operator in the subclass UString and rely on polymorhism?

Comment: `String::operator+(rhs_s);` does nothing, result is discarded, you probably want `*this = this->String::operator+(rhs_s);`

Comment: @Jarod42 `operator+` should not modify object. OP just returns wrong value.

Comment: You have a couple of functions that look like `UString UString::operator+(whatever) const` and you have `return *this;` inside each one. Without looking at any other line of the code, can you guess what these functions return?

Comment: @Slava: indeed, `UString res{this->String::operator+(rhs_s)}; return res;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
UString& UString::operator=(String const &s)
```

implementation first adds two strings, and then throws away the result, as the result is a temporary value:

```
String::operator+(rhs_s);
```

When you change it into

```
  UString UString::operator+(const UString& rhs_s) {
    return UString(String::operator+(rhs_s));
  }
```

it will return the result. To make this work, you need a constructor that takes a `String` as input, e.g.:

```
  UString UString::operator+(const UString& rhs_s) {
    return UString(String::operator+(rhs_s));
  }
```